# Hibernate HQL: Get count of results without actually returning them

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to get the count of the results of a dynamically-generated HQL query, without actually getting the list of results. Say that the query I have is something like:

```
select Company company LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH products product
```

I read in the Hibernate documentation that:

> You can count the number of query results without returning them:

```
( (Integer) session.createQuery("select count(*) from ....").iterate().next() ).intValue()
```

I suspected that I should be replacing the **....** with my query, but that does not work, as HQL does not support sub-selects in FROM.

So, how should I count the results of a dynamically generated HQL query? I think that by executing it and getting the .size() of the results list may be unnecessary overhead.

Cheers!

**UPDATE: **

I used this regex to convert my query:

```
Number num = (Number) em.createQuery(dynamicQuery.replaceAll("select \\w+ from ", "select count(*) from ")).getSingleResult();
```

And I get this:

> Blockquote
>
> EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=product,role=org.myCompany.applicant.entity.Applicant.products,tableName=PRS_DEV.PRODUCT,tableAlias=products1_,origin=PRS_DEV.APPLICANT applicant0_,colums={applicant0_.APPLICANT_ID ,className=org.myCompany.product.entity.Product}}] [**select count(*) from org.myCompany.applicant.entity.Applicant applicant LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH applicant.products product*** ]; nested exception is: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=product,role=org.myCompany.applicant.entity.Applicant.products,tableName=PRS_DEV.PRODUCT,tableAlias=products1_,origin=PRS_DEV.APPLICANT applicant0_,colums={applicant0_.APPLICANT_ID ,className=org.myCompany.product.entity.Product}}] [select count() from org.myCompany.applicant.entity.Applicant applicant LEFT OUTER JOIN FETCH applicant.products product ]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
select count(*) FROM Company c JOIN ...
```

There is no sub-select involved, just instead of returning `Company`, you return the count.

*Edit:* The `FETCH` is out of place now. You're not returning the entities from the query, but only the count, thus, Hibernate complains. Removing it should help:

```
select count(product) from org.myCompany.applicant.entity.Applicant applicant 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN applicant.products product
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. I get an exception: QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list. See my updte for the full stack trace

Answer (score 13):

you can get the count of the query result by using:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
count=(Long) criteria.uniqueResult();
```

hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't help. The rowCount() method belongs to the Criteria API, but the OP is using HQL.

Comment: I searched for Criteria API for 'count' and this hint was useful for me.