# How to get the no of records returned in Hql aggregate query without actually returning them

Tags: hibernate, hql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate HQL: Get count of results without actually returning them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198528/hibernate-hql-get-count-of-results-without-actually-returning-them)

I have a hql query like this

`select new map(t.divisionId as divisionId,t.projectId as projectId,t.roleId as roleId,t.userId as userId, t.reference as reference,t.note as note,sum(t.hoursPlanned) as hoursPlanned,sum(t.hoursUnplanned) as hoursUnplanned,sum(t.hoursPlanned) + sum(t.hoursUnplanned) as total) from TimeSheetsWork t where t.divisionId in :_divisions group by t.divisionId,t.userId,t.projectId,t.roleId`

i want to get the no of records returned from this query (without actually returning them ).
is there a way in Hibenate to do that ?? Thanx in Advance

Comment: thanx Umer, but it tells to use Criteria API but i want to get it done by using HQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need only number of records then u can use count command rather than creating map in the query like :

```
 select count(t.*) from TimeSheetsWork t where t.divisionId in :_divisions group by      
 t.divisionId,t.userId,t.projectId,t.roleId
```

Comment: Thanx mini. what i want to get done is number of records returned in the resultset.
`Session.getCurrentSession().CreateQuery("my Query ").list().size()` 
would work but i need to get it done without actually executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use this select (it also should work in HQL)

```
select count(distinct t.divisionId,t.userId,t.projectId,t.roleId) from TimeSheetsWork t where t.divisionId in :_divisions
```

In this way it only works correctly if none of the columns `t.divisionId,t.userId,t.projectId,t.roleId` have null values. If some of them have null values you can cheat and use this statement (in this example only roleId can be null):

```
select count(distinct t.divisionId,t.userId,t.projectId, coalesce(t.roleId, -1)) from TimeSheetsWork t where t.divisionId in :_divisions
```

(instead of -1 you can use any value, but it must not appear as a real roleId).

Then you use that query in HQL and you'll get a single value containing the count as the query result.